# how to proper handling typeorm entity columns in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, pg

i have been facing some difficulties in handling entity columns in coding, i mean adding or removing/deleting them from codes cause some issues in database here is how i tried to do

```
@Entity('user')
export class User {
  ....  other colums
  @Column()
  name: string;
}
```

The codes above will generate `user` table in database with appropriate column i.e name,

Now here is my issue later when i decide later to change column `name` to `fullname`

i get the following error
`QueryFailedError: column "fullname" of relation "user" contains null values`

Even if i delete the `user` table and re-running the app,

Please assist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think i found the quick solution, i had to delete `dist`folder and everything works

Answer (score 1):

To handle database modifications with TypeORM you can use two solutions, synchronize for automatic database changes and migrations for manually database changes.

**`Synchronize`**
Set the synchronize parameter to true to automatically update the database.

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      database: 'test',
      entities: [],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
```

> **WARNING**
> Setting synchronize: true shouldn't be used in production - otherwise you can lose production data.

[Learn more about synchronize](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#typeorm-integration)

**`Migrations`**
This solution is the most used and must be used in production.

`yarn typeorm migration:generate -n migrationName`

This will generate you a migration file with database instructions based on your entities. You just need to run the migrations to apply the database changes.

`yarn typeorm migration:up`

[Learn more about migrations](https://typeorm.io/#/migrations)